# Adding a keyword to standard C grammar

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I am thinking of a source-to-source compiler would like to add a keyword to the standard C grammar (say *shared*). When a pointer is being marked as *shared*, it is a special one not to be dereferenced directly. Instead, a function call should be made to copy out the value safely.

If all variables were primitive types, a simple C++ program would do the translation for me. However, we have struct and union, and then we have possibilities like struct containing shared pointers, struct containing simple pointers to shared pointers, etc. It sounds a serious type checking like handling the *volatile* keyword, probably reusing or modifying an existing compiler would be a better option. But I do not know which compiler is easier to start modifying. Do you have any suggestions? By the way, I want to see the translated C code, not the intermediate code. Would it change our choice? Thank you.

Comment: And how would you mark the function that is responsible for dereferencing each such pointer?

Comment: @unwind: if `shared` is to be treated at all like a cv-qualifier as the questioner suggests, then presumably you cast. To the questioner: this doesn't answer your question, but why not forward-declare `struct shared_Foo;` for each type `Foo` you want this for? Then `shared_Foo*` cannot be derefed, but is cast to `Foo*` by whoever should deref it. Commonly when people need opaque pointers, they're happy to have some TUs that can use them and others that cannot. So they don't even need `shared_Foo`, they just forward-declare `struct Foo` in a header and define it in the .c file.

Comment: "Standard C grammar"?  None exist in practice :-{  Lots of variants.

Comment: As for a keyword part, I'd recommend adding an attribute instead (and #define your "keyword"), it is a way much easier to do. It should be possible to implement your analysis on clang level, but much easier with an intermediate code (llvm ir), it is essentially an escape analysis. If you track (with metadata) where all you pointers came from, you can then propagate your analysis back to the AST level and emit your transformed code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of opaque types? Declare a type in a `.h` file:

```
typedef struct OpaqueType_s OpaqueType;
```

And define it in a `.c` file:

```
struct OpaqueType_s {
   int value;
};
```

Then you can dereference pointers to it in the `.c` file where
you define it, but only pass them to other functions in other files
(a bit like `void`).

Answer (score -1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) might be appropriate.

DMS provides generic parsing/AST construction, symbol table construction, control and data flow analysis facilities,  procedural APIs and surface-syntax rewrite rules for AST modification, and AST-to-compilable text regeneration (including comment regeneration).  The front ends specialize DMS to a particular language (e.g., C; DMS supports many others).  The front end is driven by a BNF; everything is built on top of that (using attribute grammars, etc.).  Dialect management enables a language front end to be specialized for a particular dialect (for C, that currently includes GCC2/3/4, MS Visual C, ANSI C, GreenHills C, C99, etc.).

To carry out OP's task, he would define a dialect for his version of C, modify the symbol table machinery provided with the front end to capture his new property on pointers, and modify the type checking to verify the new pointer types weren't misused by his definition.  With type checking out of the way, he could write source-to-source transformations to convert shared-ptrC to vanilla C to get runnable code.

Alternatives might be to use Clang or GCC, but my understanding is that neither has a grammar so the changes to the parser must be implemented as code.  Neither offers any source-to-source rewriting.  Clang I think offers source-patching but I'm not sure you can apply a series of rewrites to a place once patched.   GCC I think will let you procedurally modify the AST, but can't regenerate source code.

All of these solutions have some trouble with preprocessing.  Clang and GCC I think have to expand the preprocessor directives.  DMS has to expand unstructured directives.

Comment: We have a hit-and-run voter that *flagged* the answer but provided no comment feedback as to the complaint.  I get a lot of this; I suspect it is because of the commercial nature of DMS.  While I understand that someone might have personal reasons not to use a commercial product, that seems like a poor reason to object to the answer.